# Example pointclouds with ARCore

Tags: android, android-studio, arcore, point-clouds

Can I get some examples about pointclouds with ARCore? I really search it for days.
Currently I am working on an application similar to this one:[This app](https://www.geoweeknews.com/news/cloud-chamber-smartphone-app-captures-point-clouds-aec)

Has the feature to view pcl and save files in .ply format

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [HelloARSample](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/tree/master/samples/hello_ar_java) app renders pointcloud in a scene. You can get the coordinates for each point and save them manually in a .ply format.

Answer (score 0):

To get a point cloud, you can create a float buffer and add the points from each frame.

```
FloatBuffer myPointCloud = FloatBuffer.allocate(capacity);
Session session = new Session(context);
Frame frame = session.update();
try (PointCloud ptcld = frame.acquirePointCloud()) {
    myPointCloud.put(ptcld.getPoints());

}
```

The float buffer saves the points `like [x1,x1,z1,confidence1, x2,x2,z2,confidence2, ...]`.
I havent looked at .ply file struckture, but if you want to save it to a .pcd file, you must create a header, then insert a point per line. [Here](https://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/pcd_file_format.html/) is a detailed explanation on how to do it.

I did it like this

```
private boolean savePointCloudFile() {
        String data = "";
        String fileName = "pointCloud";
        int points = 0;
        String holder = "";

        // Write the point cloud data by iterating over each point:
        for (int i=0; i<pointCloud.position(); i+=4) {
            data += pointCloud.get(i) + " " +       // x
                    pointCloud.get(i + 1) + " " +   // y
                    pointCloud.get(i + 2) + " " +   // z
                    pointCloud.get(i + 3) + "\n";   // confidence
            points = i;
        }
        points = points / 4 - 10;   // Removed last 10 points to prevent errors in case that I lost points


        // Write file header
        data = "# .PCD v.7 - Point Cloud Data file format\n" +
                "VERSION .7\n" +
                "FIELDS x y z rgb\n" +      // confidence represented by rgb
                "SIZE 4 4 4 4\n" +          // you only have 3 values xyz
                "TYPE F F F F\n" +          // all floats
                "COUNT 1 1 1 1\n" +
                "WIDTH " + points + "\n" +
                "HEIGHT 1\n" +
                "VIEWPOINT 0 0 0 1 0 0 0\n" +
                "POINTS " + points + "\n" +
                "DATA ascii \n" + data;

        //BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        //        Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), fileName + ".pcd"));

        try {

            File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), fileName +".pcd");
            FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);

            file.createNewFile();
            //FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            stream.write(data.getBytes());
            stream.close();
            Log.i("SUCCESS", "File saved successfully in " + file.getAbsolutePath());
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
            return false;
        }
    }
```

You should save the file from within a separate thread as it may cause a timeout error, because it takes too long to save so many points to a file.

You should get a file similar to this

```
# .PCD v.7 - Point Cloud Data file format
VERSION .7
FIELDS x y z rgb
SIZE 4 4 4 4
TYPE F F F F
COUNT 1 1 1 1
WIDTH 3784
HEIGHT 1
VIEWPOINT 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
POINTS 3784
DATA ascii 
0.068493545 -0.18897545 -0.6662081 0.007968704
0.26833203 -0.18425867 -1.5039357 0.02365576
0.19286658 -0.2141684 -1.58289 0.038087178
0.070703566 -0.17931458 -0.69418937 0.016636848
0.044586033 -0.18726173 -0.6926071 0.024707714
0.04002113 -0.20350328 -0.68689686 0.018577512
0.029185327 -0.18594348 -0.73340106 0.12292312
0.0027626567 -0.20299685 -1.5578543 0.15424652
-0.031320766 -0.20478198 -0.70128816 0.13745676
-0.06351853 -0.20185146 -0.61755043 0.15234329
-0.08655308 -0.19128543 -0.6776818 0.170851
1.0159657 -0.41043654 -6.8713074 0.05946503
-0.031778865 -0.20536968 -1.5218562 0.15976532
-0.09223208 -0.19543779 -0.61643535 0.12331226
0.02384475 -0.20319816 -1.7497014 0.15273231
-0.10013421 -0.19931296 -0.5924832 0.16186734
0.49137634 -0.09052197 -5.7263794 0.16080469
```

To viaualize the point cloud you can use [pcl_viewer](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/pcl_pcd_viewer.1.html) or Matlab. In Matlab I just typed

```
ptCloud = pcread('pointCloud.pcd');
pcshow(ptCloud);
```